# Menu for hibernate does not work, pm-hibernate does

Tags: 15.10, power-management, hibernate

After upgrade to 15.10 I have been unable to activate hibernation from the start/stop menu. Doing so the following error appear in dmesg:

```
PM: Swap header not found!
```

I have checked again that my:

```
/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
```

file contains what is being advised in [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html) article.
At the same time using `sudo pm-hibernate` from the terminal works flawlessly.

Comment: Could you solve your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately No. What I was able to find out is that the menu options is calling systemd while pm-hibernate is using uswsusp. However I was unable to make systemd work with uswsusp so I gave up and just call it from command line.

Comment: What exactly happens when you use `hibernate` from menu?

Comment: Do one thing: remove those lines from the mentioned file above, restart your system, and add them again and again restart. see if it can make any difference

Comment: That somehow fixed it! Now invoking hibernate from the menu does work flawlessly! Please add this as a response so I can approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say you can use `pm-hibernate` without any problem, it means there is no issue in your hibernate setting. Therefore, the problem should be in the settings of menu button. Again, you have mentioned that you are following the same setting which was prescribed [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html).

As per my understanding, and regarding the fact that you have been facing with this right after upgrading to Ubuntu 15.10, I think your system needs a new configuration for the button. Go through these steps:

Remove the content of `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla` and restart you system. Now any configuration for the hibernate button should be removed from the system.

After booting up, open the file again and paste those few lines mentioned in the link into the file and save. Restart your system again.

If everything goes properly, the button should be configured for Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: if you see any `+50` sign on left side, please click on it as well

Comment: Unfortunately I see only this notification "This question has an open bounty worth +50 reputation from Mostafa Ahangarha ending in 4 days. " but no +50 sign to reward the points.

Comment: it is fine. most probably it is not active because I myself gave it. Enjoy your Ubuntu